# Countdown timer continues instead of starting over

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I created an on-line system module for student exams. It features multiple subjects and a timer for answering.  The student logs in and clicks on a subject.  This starts a countdown timer.

My problem is when the browser page closes for any reason.  The timer stops, which is okay.  However, when the student returns and restarts the subject, the timer continues from where it left off.  I want it to restart from the original value.

**Below screenshot:**

[image]

**View:**

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>
<div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Standard Name</th>
                <th>Subject Name</th>
                <th>Test Name</th>
                <th>Total Test Mark</th>
                <th>DateTime</th>
                <th>Percentage</th>
                <th colspan="6">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($results as $key => $value): ?>
                <?php $correct_answer = 0; ?>
                <?php $wrong_answer = 0; ?>
                <?php $per_question_mark = ($value['total_test_mark'] / $value['examination_test_question']); ?>

                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $value['standard_name']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $value['subject_name']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $key; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $value['total_test_mark']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo date("d-F-Y H:i:s", strtotime($value['time_limit'])); ?></td>

                    <?php foreach ($value['is_correct'] as $value1): ?>

                        <?php if ($value1['is_correct'] == 1): ?>
                            <?php $correct_answer+= $value1['is_correct']; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php if ($value1['is_correct'] == 0): ?>
                            <?php $wrong_answer+= 1; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php $obtain_mark = ($correct_answer * $per_question_mark); ?>
                    <?php $percentage = number_format(($obtain_mark / $value['total_test_mark'] * 100), 2); ?>
                    <td><?php echo $percentage; ?> %</td>
                    <?php //if ($percentage != 0): ?>
                    <td> <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>student/Examinations/view_answersheet/<?php echo $value['examination_test_id']; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">View AnswerSheet</a></td>
                    <?php //endif; ?>
                    <?php // if ($percentage == 0): ?>
                    <td> <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>student/Examinations/apply_examinations/<?php echo $value['examination_test_id']; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" id="apply" onclick="resetCountdownInLocalStorage();">Apply</a></td>
                    <?php //endif; ?>

                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<script>
    function resetCountdownInLocalStorage() {
        sessionStorage.removeItem("seconds");
    }
```

[image]

**View:**

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>
<?php echo form_open(); ?>

<?php foreach ($student_question as $value): ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="question_id" value="<?php echo $value['question_id']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="examination_test_id" id="examination_test_id" value="<?php echo $value['examination_test_id']; ?>">
    <?php
    $temp = array();
    $student_result = $this->db->get_where('student_answer', array('student_id' => $student_id, 'question_id' => $value['question_id']))->row_array();
    $temp['student_examination_option_id'] = $student_result['examination_option_id'];
    ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php
$examination_test_id = $this->session->userdata('examination_test_id');
$examination_test_result = $this->db->get_where('examination_test', array('examination_test_id' => $examination_test_id))->row_array();
?>
<input type="hidden" name="time_limit" id="time_limit" value="<?php echo $examination_test_result['time_limit']; ?>">

<div class="box-body">
    <h2><p style="float: right" id="countdown"></p></h2>
    <input type="hidden" name="student_id" id="student_id" value="<?php echo $student_id; ?>">
    <table>
        <?php foreach ($result as $key => $value): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><h3><?php echo $key; ?></h3></td>
                <?php foreach ($value as $options): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="option_id" value="<?php echo $options['examination_option_id'] ?>"
                        <?php
                        if ($temp['student_examination_option_id'] == $options['examination_option_id']) {
                            echo 'checked';
                        }
                        ?>>&nbsp;<?php echo $options['option_name']; ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
    <div class="box-footer" style="float: right">
        <p><?php echo $links; ?>&nbsp;<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>student/Examinations/check_answer/<?php echo $examination_test_id; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" id="finish" style="font-size: 20px;">Finish</a></p>
    </div>

</div>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>

<!--<script src="<?php //echo base_url();                                                                                    ?>asset/plugins/countdowntimer/jquery.simple.timer.js"></script>-->

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#next').click(function () {
            var str = $("input[type='radio'],input[type='hidden']").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                type: 'POST',
                url: base_url + "student/Examinations/submit_answer",
                data: str,
                success: function () {

                }
            });

        });
        // });


        $examination_test_id = $("#examination_test_id").val();
        $time_limit = $("#time_limit").val();
        var d = new Date($time_limit);
        var hours = d.getHours();
        var minute = d.getMinutes();
        var minutes = hours * 60 + minute;
        var seconds = 60 * minutes;

        if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
            if (sessionStorage.seconds) {
                seconds = sessionStorage.seconds;
            }
        }
        function secondPassed() {
            var hours = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
            var minutes = Math.floor((seconds - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
            //   var remainingSeconds = seconds - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);
            var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;

            if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
                remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;
            }
            if (minutes < 10) {
                minutes = "0" + minutes;
            }

            if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
                sessionStorage.setItem("seconds", seconds);
            }

            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;

            if (seconds == 0) {
                clearInterval(myVar);
                document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = alert('Timeout');
                window.location.href = base_url + "student/Examinations/check_answer/" + $examination_test_id;

                if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
                    sessionStorage.removeItem("seconds");
                }
            } else {
                seconds--;
            }
        }
        var myVar = setInterval(secondPassed, 1000);
    });

</script>
<style>
    .btn-primary a{
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
</style>
```

Please check my JavaScript code.

Comment: I tried my best to format the question in english better. I can't understand what you're trying to do/accomplish, and I suggest you try to reword the first few paragraphs so others can help you.

Comment: @FrankerZ above screenshot-1 in i click any one exam and countdown timer start ,any reasone my browser page close then countdown timer stop and after few miniutes i click same examination and countdown timer countinue ,can not start begining

Comment: That didn't help in the slightest

Comment: @FrankerZ you use github or bitbucket ?

Comment: Cleaned up problem description.